# TFS .Net REST API access with PAT

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have a code in C# that access TFS Rest API.
When I use the following code:

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(orgUrl, new VssCredentials());
```

I get the results I need.

When trying to set the credentials:

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(orgUrl, credentials);
```

I get an error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

The error occurs when the following code line is committed:

```
WorkItem workitem = witClient.GetWorkItemAsync(workItemId).Result;
```

Full code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
            Uri orgUrl = new Uri("my uri");                       
            string personalAccessToken = "my token"; 
            int workItemId = 486915;   

        // Create a connection
        VssCredentials credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", personalAccessToken);
        VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(orgUrl, credentials);

        //VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(orgUrl, new VssCredentials());

        // Show details a work item
        ShowWorkItemDetails(connection, workItemId);

        Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void ShowWorkItemDetails(VssConnection connection, int workItemId)
{
        // Get an instance of the work item tracking client
        WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

        // Get the specified work item
        WorkItem workitem = witClient.GetWorkItemAsync(workItemId).Result;

            // Output the work item's field values
            foreach (var field in workitem.Fields)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}: {1}", field.Key, field.Value);
            }
}
```

Comment: You're getting an `AggregateException` because you're not `await`ing the method call. Look at the inner exception for the actual error.

Comment: Daniel, thank you for editing the question. Can you please provide more details about he await part?

Comment: So I just ran you code and it works fine.  Like Daniel mentions you could add async (between public and static on the ShowWorkItemDetails method and then add await on the line where you call GetWorkItemAsync (make sure to remove the .results at the end).